# Pretty printing zeros in data.frame with integers and doubles to CSV

Tags: r, csv

I have the following data.frame:

```
q <- data.frame(A = rep(0,12), B = rep(c(0,1),6), C = 0:11, D = c(rep(0.0,10),0.003579535,0.045418328), E = c(rep(0.0,10),0.001716128,0.057440227))

> q
   A B  C           D           E
1  0 0  0 0.000000000 0.000000000
2  0 1  1 0.000000000 0.000000000
3  0 0  2 0.000000000 0.000000000
4  0 1  3 0.000000000 0.000000000
5  0 0  4 0.000000000 0.000000000
6  0 1  5 0.000000000 0.000000000
7  0 0  6 0.000000000 0.000000000
8  0 1  7 0.000000000 0.000000000
9  0 0  8 0.000000000 0.000000000
10 0 1  9 0.000000000 0.000000000
11 0 0 10 0.003579535 0.001716128
12 0 1 11 0.045418328 0.057440227
```

I would like to save it in a CSV with the following format:

```
"A","B","C","D","E"
0,0,0,0.000000000,0.000000000
0,1,1,0.000000000,0.000000000
0,0,2,0.000000000,0.000000000
0,1,3,0.000000000,0.000000000
0,0,4,0.000000000,0.000000000
0,1,5,0.000000000,0.000000000
0,0,6,0.000000000,0.000000000
0,1,7,0.000000000,0.000000000
0,0,8,0.000000000,0.000000000
0,1,9,0.000000000,0.000000000
0,0,10,0.003579535,0.001716128
0,1,11,0.045418328,0.057440227
```

How can I get it in that format? I'm not sure how to use the existing functionality in `print`,`format`, and `formatC` to do this before calling `write.csv`. The first three columns should be printed as integers and the last two columns should be printed as doubles to 9 decimal places, including the zeros.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Excel reads columns as General by default, so 0.000 will be shown as 0 anyways. Format the columns to "Number" with desired precision?

Comment: It certainly looks like that works as a temporary solution. Unfortunately in the longer term I'll probably need to do this in R directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?write.csv` explains how to do this:

> In almost all cases the conversion of numeric quantities is governed
>   by the option "scipen" (see options), but with the internal equivalent
>   of digits = 15. For finer control, use format to make a character
>   matrix/data frame, and call write.table on that.

Indeed, the default arguments to `format` are sufficient for your needs:

```
write.csv(format(q),row.names=FALSE)
"A","B","C","D","E"
"0","0","0","0.000000000","0.000000000"
"0","1","1","0.000000000","0.000000000"
"0","0","2","0.003579535","0.001716128"
"0","1","3","0.045418328","0.057440227"
```

Due to the various conventions you want to apply to your data, I think you will have to do the header and data separately:

```
# write header
write.csv(q[0,],"mydata.csv",row.names=FALSE)
# "A","B","C","D","E"

# add data
write.table(format(q,trim=TRUE),"mydata.csv",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,sep=",",quote=FALSE,append=TRUE)
# 0,0,0,0.000000000,0.000000000
# 0,1,1,0.000000000,0.000000000
# 0,0,2,0.000000000,0.000000000
# 0,1,3,0.000000000,0.000000000
# 0,0,4,0.000000000,0.000000000
# 0,1,5,0.000000000,0.000000000
# 0,0,6,0.000000000,0.000000000
# 0,1,7,0.000000000,0.000000000
# 0,0,8,0.000000000,0.000000000
# 0,1,9,0.000000000,0.000000000
# 0,0,10,0.003579535,0.001716128
# 0,1,11,0.045418328,0.057440227
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need it without the quotes (for the values)... the csv is fed into a third-party tool that I cannot modify.

Comment: Add `quote=FALSE` to the `write.csv` call

Comment: `quote=FALSE` disables quotes for everything including the column names. The column names need to be quoted but the values should not be. I also tried scipen but it looks like it prints `0.000000000` as `0` (when not using format). The other problem is that `format` adds spaces to values when they are shorter than the longest value, i.e. `,0,` becomes `, 0,` if any of the other rows has a value in that column which two digits long.

Comment: Use `trim = TRUE` as an argument to `format` to solve the leading space issue. I'll post an alternative solution to get everything you want, but it won't be as neat.

Comment: Actually I think it's a fine idea to split the header from the values given that the conventions are different. I hadn't thought of it!